# Simple filter on array of RXJS Observable

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am starting my project with Angular2 and the developers seem to recommend RXJS Observable instead of Promises.

I have achieved to retrieve a list of elements (epics) from the server.
But how can I filter the elments by using for example an id?

The following code is an extraction from my app and shows now the final working solution. Let's hope it helps someone.

```
@Injectable()
export class EpicService {

  private url = CONFIG.SERVER + '/app/';  // URL to web API

  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  private extractData(res:Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body;
  }

  getEpics():Observable<Epic[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + "getEpics")
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getEpic(id:string): Observable<Epic> {
    return this.getEpics()
      .map(epics => epics.filter(epic => epic.id === id)[0]);
  }
}

export class EpicComponent {

  errorMessage:string;
  epics:Epic[];
  epic:Epic;

  constructor(
    private requirementService:EpicService) {
  }

  getEpics() {
    this.requirementService.getEpics()
      .subscribe(
        epics => this.epics = epics,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  // actually this should be eventually in another component
  getEpic(id:string) {
    this.requirementService.getEpic(id)
        .subscribe(
        epic => this.epic = epic,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}

export class Epic {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you should have left the original question as is, this way we will never know what "not" to do

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You'll want to filter the actual array and not the observable wrapped around it.
So you'll map the content of the Observable (which is an `Epic[]`) to a filtered `Epic`.

```
getEpic(id: string): Observable<Epic> {
  return this.getEpics()
     .map(epics => epics.filter(epic => epic.id === id)[0]);
}
```

Then afterwards you can `subscribe` to `getEpic` and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Looks simple but: Error:(33, 42) TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'. I will update question, to show the whole component and service relationship.

Comment: Well if it's that then you can just convert from string to number or number to string :)

Answer (score 41):

You can do this using the `flatMap` and `filter` methods of `Observable` instead of the JS array filter method in `map`.  Something like:

```
this.getEpics() 
    .flatMap((data) => data.epics) // [{id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 3}, ..., {id: N}]
    .filter((epic) => epic.id === id) // checks {id: 1}, then {id: 2}, etc
    .subscribe((result) => ...); // do something epic!!!
```

`flatMap` will provide singular indices for filtering and then you can get on with whatever happens next with the results.

If TypeScript throws a error indicating you can't compare a string and a number regardless of your use of `==` in the filter just add a `+` before `epic.id` in the filter, per the Angular docs:

```
    .flatMap(...)
    .filter((epic) => +epic.id === id) // checks {id: 1}, then {id: 2}, etc
    .subscribe(...)
```

**Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ehje5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is much cleaner than the accepted answer and makes full use of Rx. The proper way to perform this operation is to use `flatMap` as the author has pointed out.

Comment: If epics ist an array (like you suggest), one can not flatMap to `data.epics`. And you also can not filter the array like you wrote.

Comment: @StefanRein I would argue that you should try the code out first then comment - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ehje5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @mtpultz Yes, I did copy your comment from SO as input. Your comment for the method getEpics() here on SO should be: `// { epics: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}] }` and not `// [{id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 3}, ..., {id: N}]` like in the Stackblitz example.. that confused me, thanks. Should've looked int the Stackblitz example, too :)

Comment: I've moved the comment down one line

Answer (score 8):

original answer with a fix: 
`Observables` are lazy. You have to call `subscribe` to tell an `observable` to send its request.

```
  getEpic(id:number) {
    return this.getEpics()
           .filter(epic => epic.id === id)
           .subscribe(x=>...);
  }
```

Update to Rxjs 6:

```
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

getEpic(id:number) {
        return this.getEpics()
               .pipe(filter(epic => epic.id === id))
               .subscribe(x=>...);
      }
```

Comment: The return type of subscribe is a Subscription, which implements ISubscription. Both do not have a filter method.

Comment: @StefanRein, in the original question `this.getEpics()` returns observable of an *Array*. So, `filter` is a method of *Array*

Comment: You are right. Just in your answer you are chaining the filter after the subscribe method, which has not a filter method, thus my comment

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe on `Observable`s to get the data, since http calls are async in JavaScript.

```js
getEpic(id: number, callback: (epic: Epic) => void) {
    this.getEpics().subscribe(
        epics: Array<Epic> => {
            let epic: Epic = epics.filter(epic => epic.id === id)[0];
            callback(epic);
        }
    );
}
```

You can call that method then like this:

```
this.someService.getEpic(epicId, (epic: Epic) => {
    // do something with it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone trying to use `flatMap`, it is deprecated currently and rxJs recommends using `mergeMap` instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34212833)