# Angular 2 filter an Observabble<object[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to show a list of `IMessage` on screen and be able to filter them using a `Pipe`.
The message is actually an `Observable<IMessage[]>` on which I want to filter each `IMessage` by checking its `isPrivate` property.
The code of the `MessageStatusPipe` looks like this:

```
export class MessageStatusPipe {
    transform(message: Observable<IMessage[]>, privateFilter: bool) {


        //Here I want to return the Messages which the pass the privateFilter, but how?

    }
}
```

I have read some questions which seem very similar but I don't seem to be able to apply that solution.
The following solution by Luka Jacobowitz seems exactly what I need.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991713/simple-filter-on-array-of-rxjs-observable#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991713/simple-filter-on-array-of-rxjs-observable#_=_)

============ Update with answer =============

As Meir pointed out the pipe returned a bool value instead of a sub array containing items that matched the filter. My working pipe now looks like this:

```
export class MessageStatusPipe {
    transform(messages: Observable<IMessage[]>, privateFilter: bool) {
        return messages.map(m => m.filter((message, i) => {
            return message.isPrivate == privateFilter;
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action can (should) be broken into 2 parts:
1. Getting the async values
2. Filtering them

So, you can change your pipe's signature to:

```
transform(messages: IMessage[], privateFilter: bool) { ... }
```

And in your component do:

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of messages | async | messageStatusPipe">...</div>
```

If for some reason you want to combine them into one pipe, you can have a look at an [article I wrote](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/asyncorvalue-pipe-angular2-meir-shahar) that shows how to handle async values inside a pipe and adapt it to your needs (mainly, add your filtering loging)

============ added filter logic ==============

```
return messages.filter(privateFilter);
```

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let msg of messages | async | messageStatusPipe">...</div>`
That is actually what I already have in my component.

`transform(messages: IMessage[], privateFilter: bool) { ... }`
That is was my pipe used to look like but that gave an `Observable<IMessage>` on which I wasnt able to apply the filter.

Comment: Your pipe should not return a bool, it should return the sub array that matches your condition

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer with a working solution.