# rxjs Filter an array of objects observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have now this piece of code to filter an observable.

`listings$: Observable<Listing[]>;`

```
this.listings$ = this.firestore
      .getListings()
      .pipe(map(listings => listings.filter(listing => listing.promoted === true)));
```

Which works fine, but I want to make full use of rxjs instead of using the `filter` on the array.

The `this.firestore.getListings()` function returns `Observable<Listing[]>`, and `this.listings$` must be `Observable<Listing[]>` as well.

I tried different approaches, and struggling with this for a while. Maybe you can help me. I'm still "fresh" to angular and rxjs.

```
this.listings$ = this.firestore.getListings().pipe(
      mergeMap(listings => listings),
      filter(listing => listing.promoted === true)
    );
```

> Type `Observable<Listing>` is not assignable to type `Observable<Listing[]>`.

I might be doing something wrong with the `mergeMap` operator, or even it is not correct operator to use in this case.

I tried to adjust the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43219046/1786842) post. The `flatMap` operator seem to be changed to `mergeMap`. But it's still not working.

Comment: Using rxjs map and array filter is absolutely a proper way of doing it. Don't go out of your way to change it.

Comment: It looks like the error is caused by the type given to `this.listings$`. Outside of the code shown, you must adjust the code to match an observable stream of individual listing objects. I guess that form is more convenient for your view?

Comment: @eric99 I didn't add this part of code in my post. But however it is `listings$: Observable<Listing[]>;`

Comment: Thanks for that info. So why exactly are you trying to flatten the observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this depends on how you want to use the `this.listings$` Observable. Using `mergeMap(listings => listings)` is correct and it turns `Observable<Listing[]>` into `Observable<Listing>` but you said you want to use RxJS `filter()` operator and you want to have `Observable<Listing[]>` at the end anyway.

One way could be using `take(1)` and `toArray()` operators. `toArray()` will accumulate all emissions from its source into a single array and when the source competes it emits the array.

```
this.listings$ = this.firestore.getListings().pipe(
  take(1),
  mergeMap(listings => listings),
  filter(listing => listing.promoted === true),
  toArray(),
);
```

Note that this `listings$` Observable will emit just once and won't react to any subsequent emissions from `this.firestore.getListings()`.

Personally, I'd actually use what you had `pipe(map(listings => listings.filter(...)))` because this is just easier to use.

Comment: Thanks. `this.listings$` is `Observable<Listing[]>` so I can subscribe to it and get listings displayed over time as they are added, so `take(1)` is not what I want. I will mark your answer as accepted because you actually covered more than I expected someone would answer.